# Pedersen Hash : when truncating the hash to keep only the X coordinate, is it possible to compute a collision when the Babyjubjub curve is used?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, collision-attack

The Pedersen hash is a low constraints friendly hash for Zk-Snarks.
Unlike many algorithms, the Pedersen hash returns a point `P = (x,y)` on a curve as a hash. **Depending on the selected curve**, there can exist a fast deterministic way to compute a different input that yields `−P=(x,−y)` using the Weierstrass form.

As a result, if software chooses to truncate a hash to its first half, and if the attacker controls the fixed length input, then there’s the possibility to compute 2 inputs that will yield the same truncated hash.

But can this situation happen if the Pedersen is implemented over the BabyJubJub curve ? **Also, are there inputs that can yield special values on the curve such as `−INF` or 0 at least for `x` or does it behave like more conventional hashing algorithms** ? Even in the Edwards form, can it still works defeat a `===` constraint (`x` is equal to `−x`) as circom and Groth16 is mainly about modulos ?
**And if yes, how exactly this can be computed in practice in that case ?**

The definition of the hash in the case of that specific  curve is [here](https://iden3-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iden3_repos/research/publications/zkproof-standards-workshop-2/pedersen-hash/pedersen.html).

Comment: The implementation I’m talking about is [here](https://github.com/kobigurk/circomlib/blob/feat/audit_fixes/circuits/pedersen.circom), and the size of the attacker controlled message is fixed to 505bits.

Comment: That impl appears to be returning both coordinates. Would this attack be for a different, weakened system?

Comment: @rozbb the software behind it takes only `out[0]` and discard `out[1]` which is `y`. But this could be a design choice since the chosen `JubJub` curve might ensure security even in that case.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: I believe this does not degrade security**

Summary: For reasonable choice of basis for the Pedersen hash $\mathsf{PH}$, it is the case that
$$
\mathsf{xcoord}(\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a)) = \mathsf{xcoord}(\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a'))
\implies
\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a) = \mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a').
$$
In other words, dropping the y-coordinate doesn't give you any advantage in finding collisions.

First, some math. What happens algebraically when you flip the y-coordinate of a Twisted Edwards curve? Recall the addition law for a curve of the form $ax^2 + y^2 = 1 + dx^2y^2$:

$$
(x_1, y_1) + (x_2, y_2) = \left(
\frac{x_1y_2 + y_1x_2}{1 + dx_1x_2y_1y_2},
\frac{y_1y_2 - ax_1x_2}{1 - dx_1x_2y_1y_2}
\right).
$$

Let $g(H)$ map a curve point $H = (x,y)$ to its x-reflection $(x, -y)$. Observe that, for any $H$,
$$
H + g(H)
= (x, y) + (x, -y) = \left(
\frac{xy - yx}{1 + dx^2y^2},
\frac{y^2 - ax^2}{1 - dx^2y^2}
\right)
= (0,-1)
=: Q.
$$
Thus, $g(H) = Q - H$ for all $H$. Also note, $Q$ has order 2, i.e., $Q + Q = \mathcal{O}$.

This is helpful for our characterization of collisions. Since the curve intersects any vertical line in at most two points, we have that for any two curve points $H \neq H'$,
$$
\mathsf{xcoord}(H) = \mathsf{xcoord}(H')
\iff H = g(H')
\iff H = Q - H'.
$$

What happens if we try to get an "easy" hash collision, i.e., getting a collision in the x-coordinate but not the y-coordinate? Let $\mathsf{PH}$ denote Pedersen hash function, mapping $k$ scalars $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in \mathbb F$ to $a_1 G_1 + \ldots + a_kG_k$, where $\{G_i\}$ denotes the Pedersen basis. An "easy" collision occurs with inputs $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf a'$ when $\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a) \neq \mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a')$, and
\begin{align*}
&\mathsf{xcoord}(\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a)) = \mathsf{xcoord}(\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a'))
\\&\iff \mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a) = Q - \mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a')
\\&\iff {\textstyle\sum} a_iG_i = Q - {\textstyle\sum} a'_iG_i
\\&\iff {\textstyle\sum} (a_i + a'_i)G_i = Q.
\end{align*}

For certain choices of Pedersen basis $\{G_i\}$, this is a contradiction! If you select each $G_i$ from the large prime-order subgroup (a reasonable thing to do, since torsion is a headache in many protocols anyway), then you have that the LHS of the last equality is in the subgroup and the RHS is not. So if $(x,y)$ is an output of a $\mathsf{PH}$ with this kind of basis, then $(x, -y)$ *cannot* be an output of $\mathsf{PH}$.

Thus, the only way you can get an x-coordinate collision $\mathsf{xcoord}(\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a)) = \mathsf{xcoord}(\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a'))$ is to get a real collision $\mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a) = \mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a')$

## Old Answer (ignore)

Outputting only the x-coordinate makes it trivial to find a collision.

Let $G_1, G_2, \ldots, G_k \in \mathbb G$ represent the Pedersen basis. The input to the Pedersen hash function $\mathsf H$ is $k$ scalars $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in \mathbb F$ and is mapped to the x-coordinate of $a_1G_1 + \ldots a_kG_k$.

Recall for any elliptic curve point $H = (x,y)$, it is the case that $-H = (x, -y)$. In other words, you get the negative by reflecting across the x-axis. The upshot is that for all $H$, $\mathsf{xcoord}(H) = \mathsf{xcoord}(-H)$.

Applying this to Pedersen, we get a collision:
$$
\mathsf H(a_1, \ldots, a_k)
=
\mathsf{xcoord}(a_1G_1 + \ldots a_kG_k)
=
\mathsf{xcoord}(-(a_1G_1 + \ldots a_kG_k))
=
\mathsf H(-a_1, \ldots, -a_k)
$$

Comment: the Jujube curve is a curve in Edwards form where the inverse $(x,y)$ is $(-x,y)$.

Comment: @DanielS so his answer is wrong?

Comment: @user2284570 I can't see a way to apply their argument to the Edwards curve case.

Comment: Oh I apologize I misread the question. I think this is secure. I will post my thoughts tonight

Comment: @DanielS even in the Edwards form, can it still works defeat a `==` constraint as circom and Groth16 is mainly about modulos ? I m meaning, does circom takes care of the sign of integers or can an integer equals its negative equivalent in circom ?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @rozbb so getting `−x` from Input `M` remains possible ? If yes, what about the equality comparison `==` in Groth16 and thus circom considering how negative numbers are encoded with the chosen finite field ?

Comment: Yes, separately from what was addressed in the answer, if $H =(x,y) = \mathsf{PH}(\mathbf a)$ for some $\mathbf a$, then $-H =(-x,y) = \mathsf{PH}(-\mathbf a)$. This equality holds in the finite field your proof system uses, because Jubjub is explicitly chosen so that $x,y$ are BLS12-318 scalar field elements.

Comment: @rozbb then, what about the equality comparison `===` in circom with Groth16 considering how negative numbers are encoded with the chosen finite field ? (Since it s about modulos)

Comment: The circom `===` operator tests equality over the finite field. The encoding doesn't matter here. It should behave as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking negative numbers where larger than `p`. But as I m not an expert on this, would it be possible to have sample code for the actual implementation for computing an input `M'` from `M` than turn `x` into `−x` anyway?

Comment: @DanielS I m noting that in the implementation, the computations are done using BabyJubJub as a Montgomery curve instead of edward and later converted to the Edwards form. Does this change something?

Comment: @user2284570 That doesn't change anything as the same answer could have been produced by using Edwards form throughout.

Comment: @DanielS I’m also noting the generated hash is the [BabyJubJub coordinate addition](https://github.com/kobigurk/circomlib/blob/4284dc1ef984a204db08864f5da530c97f9376ef/circuits/pedersen.circom#L229) of Pedersen Hash of [several unpacked 4 bits Pedersen hash](https://github.com/kobigurk/circomlib/blob/4284dc1ef984a204db08864f5da530c97f9376ef/circuits/pedersen.circom#L206) (x and y points) . Does this even mean getting `−x` from modifying `M` is impossible ?

Comment: @user2284570 No, although it is not obvious, if you work through the details of the bit-unpacking where we have a message $M$ such that $e(M)=c$ where $e$ is the unpacking function $b_0b_1b_2b_3=(2b_3-1)(1+2b_0+4b_1+8b_2)$ applied nybble-wise, then flipping all of the $b_3$ bits gives a message $M'$ such that $e(M')=-c$.

Comment: @DanielS thanks. [There’s no bit packing](https://github.com/kobigurk/circomlib/blob/4284dc1ef984a204db08864f5da530c97f9376ef/circuits/pedersen.circom#L237).  Sorry to maybe write stupid garbage questions as I’m not an expert, but does [a BabyJubJub addition affect both coordinates](https://github.com/kobigurk/circomlib/blob/4284dc1ef984a204db08864f5da530c97f9376ef/circuits/babyjub.circom#L23) ? I’m meaning that the value of `x1` or `x2` along `y1` and `y2` affect the value of `yout` and that the value of `y1` and `y2` affect `xout` ?

Comment: @DanielS JubJub isn t Edwards but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_Edwards_curve. Does this change something?

Comment: No, the above answer applies to any Twisted Edwards curve

Comment: @rozbb As I notice a seed… and more generally : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/107320/59586 ?