# Is it possible to get the negative point with −x in that version of the Pedersen hash over the BaybyJubJub curve?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, collision-attack

The Pedersen hash is a low constraints friendly hash for Zk-Snarks.
Unlike many algorithms, the Pedersen hash returns a point `P = (x,y)` on a curve as a hash. Depending on the selected curve, there can exist a fast deterministic way to compute a different input that yields `−P=(x,−y)` using the Weierstrass form or `−P=(−x,y)` in the twisted Edwards form like the case here with BabyJubJub.

[But in the current variant that interests me, `M` is hashed into individual segments of 200Bits and each coordinate/hash is added over the BabyJubJub curve](https://iden3-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iden3_repos/research/publications/zkproof-standards-workshop-2/pedersen-hash/pedersen.html#set-of-generators). But more importantly, each 200bits segment is seeded by a different [static Montgomery point/initialisation vector](https://github.com/kobigurk/circomlib/blob/4284dc1ef984a204db08864f5da530c97f9376ef/circuits/pedersen.circom#L125).

[Does the use of different initialisation vector](https://github.com/kobigurk/circomlib/blob/4284dc1ef984a204db08864f5da530c97f9376ef/circuits/pedersen.circom#L184), means it’s that time impossible to modify `M` to get `−P` from `P` even in the Edwards form ?
Also, is [`There are potentials issues with this approach where collisions can happen`](https://iden3-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iden3_repos/research/publications/zkproof-standards-workshop-2/pedersen-hash/pedersen.html#challenges) only possible if `M`’s length isn’t a multiple of 4 ?